# Installing engineered hardwood to exposed edges

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, engineered-flooring

I'm about to begin removing carpet and installing some engineered wood floors in one of the rooms of my house.  The only thing I'm unsure of at the moment is how the boards should be installed for areas where they will be tight against an edge and not covered by baseboard trim.

In this particular room there are 4 instances of this: the bottom of a step, the edge of the floor, in front of french doors, and around stone slabs at the fireplace.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All edges need to be concealed by trim, whether it's baseboard, base shoe, transition strip, or termination molding.

In most of the cases you mentioned, a simple L-molding should do, such as against the stair railing board. Obviously your stairs are getting some new treatment or other, so that could serve as the overlay.

Consider cutting channels under your stone with an appropriate saw so your flooring can slip beneath it. This would be the most professional and aesthetically-pleasing solution.

Comment: 3/4" X 3/4"  QUARTER ROUND WORKS WELL TOO.

Comment: That's the base shoe I mentioned. Some find quarter-round too obtrusive when the base trim is much thinner than 3/4".